# Javascript regex to match exact folder path

Tags: javascript, regex, istanbul, karma-coverage, isparta

I have a folder structure like this:

```
main
|__Test
   |__Sub
      |__Match
      |__Match1
      |__Match2
```

I have a requirement to:

1. Match only one folder - "Match"
2. Match multiple folder - "Match, Match1, Match2

For a) I've tried:

```
/main\/Test\/Sub\/Match\//
```

But that didn't help.

Basically, I am using [Isparta](https://www.npmjs.com/package/isparta-instrumenter-loader), and I need to exclude a few folders from instrumentation.

Comment: Maybe you need to replace the final `\/` with `$`? Try `/main\/Test\/Sub\/Match$/`

Comment: noops that didn't help.

Comment: Try this: `/^main\/Test\/Sub\/Match(\d+)?$^/`, test: https://regex101.com/r/lWauGN/1/

Comment: no that also didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
\/main\/Test\/Sub\/Match([0-9])?\/?
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/^main\/Test\/Sub\/Match[0-9]?\/?$/
```

I used `[0-9]` because you mentioned a structure Like. Assume there are not only match1 and match2.

Comment: Yes. This understanding is correct but this regex didn't help

Comment: Please define _didn't help_

Comment: I meant it didn't really work for my scenario. I was expecting it to match folder pattern. But it didn't work for excluding folders with Isparta to exclude certain folders from instrumentations. 

May be something wrong at my end.